# WebStorm Node.js debugger just executing but not stopping for the breakpoints

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

I am using WebStorm and have added a remote server, now I am trying to debug my app and for that, I have added some breakpoints in some of my routes files and app.js.

Now the thing happening is that all my static breakpoints (when my code is compiled) are executing and my debugger is stopping for them but after that when I call any of my code in my route file then the breakpoint there just get a tick mark (executes) but debugger didn't stop for that breakpoint. So because of that, I am not able to see any variable data at that breakpoint and it is happening every time and for all routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad Actually I was using Google Compute Engine as the remote server, and as per google docs I have attached the google-cloud debugger from the beginning because of which the IDE debugger was never getting attached, after commenting it debugging is happening correctly :)

> require('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start({ allowExpressions: true });